# How to combine MYSQL Left Join and Group By for another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case, where-clause

I am using mysql and have two tables user and result.

```
      `user`                                 `result`
---------------------------          -------------------------------------
| `id`  | `name` |`active`|          | `id` |`user_id` |`status`|`identity`|
--------------------------            ------------------------------------
|   1   | Apia   | 1    |            |   1   |    1   |    2   |    1   |
|   2   | Tang   | 1    |            |   2   |    1   |    2   |    1   |
|   3   | Jemrom | 1    |            |   3   |    2   |    1   |    1   |
|   4   | Akwet  | 1    |            |   4   |    5   |    3   |    1   |
|   5   | Lamte  | 1    |            -------------------------------------
---------------------------
```

So the result should look like:

```
------------------------------
| `name` |`active` |`status`  |
------------------------------
| Apia   |    1    |`passed`  |
| Tang   |    1    |`passed`  |
| Akwet  |    1    |`awaiting`|
| Lamte  |    1    |`failed`  |
| Jerome  |    1    |`unavailable`  |
------------------------------
```

So far, I have:

```
SELECT     u.*, 
           r.status
FROM       user u 
LEFT JOIN result r 
ON         r.user_id = u.id 
WHERE u.active = 1;
```

But I don't know how to write the query for result table aspect.

NB: For status in result table (1=awaiting, 2=passed,3=failed)

I want to select everything from user table using left join where active = 1 (ordered by names)  and match with related user_id in result table where identity =1. The result table must be grouped by user_id.
Where a user does not have data in result, it should display unavailable for status instead of null.

How do I write this query in MYSQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a `left join` and aggregation. Your question is unclear about how you want to compute the status when a user has more than one result, so I assumed you want the maximum value:

```
select
    u.name,
    u.active,
    case max(r.status)
        when 1 then 'awaiting'
        when 2 then 'passed'
        when 3 then 'failed'
        else 'unavailable'
    end as status
from users u
left join result r on r.user_id = u.id and r.identity = 1
where u.active = 1
group by u.id, u.name, u.active
```

Note that `user` is a language keyword in MySQL (as well as in most other databases), hence a poor choice for a table name. I renamed it to `users` inthe query.

Comment: Yes, I want left join and aggregation, but the is only for user_id in result and not for name in user. It should only affect the result table. The left join aspect is okay as it is, but the only issue is the group by.

Comment: @mikefolu: just add the user id to the `group by` clause. The other columns are functionaly dependent on the `id` anyway.

Comment: Sorry @Gmb, it like you don't understand me. user_id appears multiple time in result. If I use group by for the whole query, it will want me to add each field in user table to the group by in case I am having other fields apart from  u.name,u.active. So I want the group by to only affect the result table. Kindly assist